# How to use vue-meta-3 useAPI outside setup function?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-meta

I'm attempting to use the vue-meta-3 useApi outside the setup function in order to access data associated with my component and to add it to the meta tags. According to the docs https://github.com/nuxt/vue-meta/tree/next#quick-usage this should be possible. However when I do this then the child components metadata no longer overwrites the parent component.

If I use setup functions then the child metadata does overwrite the parent but I can't access the components data in the setup function (without some hacks that Vue doesn't recommend such as using getComponentInstance).

Note I'm storing my metaManager in Vuex and I access it in the child components.

This is what I'm calling in the mount function

```js
useMeta(
  {
    title: 'Offer',
    og: {
      description: ` is the description`,
    },
  },
  this.metaManager
);
```

Comment: Can you clarify? What exactly is the code that you have and what does not work as intended? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . `this.metaManager` - what is the context for this code? `this` is generally not used in Vue 3.

Comment: @EstusFlask when I use that code in the setup() function (minus the this.metaManager) then everything works as intended and the child meta tags overwrite the parents. But when I use it outside of the setup() function. Right now I'm doing it in mounted(), then I need to reference the metaManager, but doing it this way doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Please, update the code. "Outside setup function" is ambiguous. It could mean that you try to use it outside the component. "According to the docs" - this is what docs show. Do you mean there's mounted alongside setup? Then this is the problem in the first place. setup is supposed to replace everything from options API, including lifecycle hooks.

Comment: `use` are generally supposed to be used directly in setup. They aren't guaranteed to work normally anywhere else. Whether they suppose the use outside setup depends on internals of a specific function. Vue builtins  like `ref` support this, but if a hook relies on getComponentInstance (which is very common), it's available only in setup.